# Trying to make two max function work

Tags: sql, subquery, max

Hi wanted to make this two max functions work, where did I went wrong with my query? It won't return any error but only one of the max in my WHERE statement works. Here is the query

```
SELECT g.studentid, g.blockcode, sb.subjectcode, sb.daystart,sb.block,sb.dayend,
       sb.stime, sb.sday, ii.firstname instructorname,  ii.lastname instructorlastname, 
       sb.roomcode, r.building, d.description, rr.studentid,rr.sem, rr.sy
FROM grades g 
JOIN subjectblocking sb ON g.blockcode=sb.blockcode
JOIN instructorinfo ii ON sb.instructorid=ii.instructorid
JOIN subjects d ON sb.subjectcode = d.subjectcode
JOIN room r ON sb.roomcode=r.roomcode
JOIN register rr ON rr.studentid=g.studentid
WHERE g.studentid='$studentid'
AND rr.sem = (SELECT max(sem) 
              FROM register
              WHERE sy = (SELECT max(sy) from register))
ORDER BY  sb.daystart ASC, sb.stime like '%AM%' DESC;
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: How can you tell only one of those max'es work? You won't see their value in the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute

```
SELECT max(sy) from register
```

by itself. What do you get? Is it the value you expect? Then execute

```
SELECT max(sem) 
FROM register
WHERE sy = (SELECT max(sy) from register)
```

by itself. What do you get? Is it the value you expect? If it is not what you expect, try hard coding the value from the first query:

```
SELECT max(sem) 
FROM register
WHERE sy = 2015
```

If the value now is correct, then there is a problem nesting the two queries. You don't specify the DBMS you are using, but that is not a problem I would expect to see in any commercial or even popular open source systems.

If this double Max-of-a-Max structure is commonly used in your queries, you might want to create a calculated column called, oh, `sysem` defined as `sy * 10 + sem`. This is assuming sem is a very small value in the range 1-4. The result would look like this:

```
sy    sem  sysem
====  ===  ======
2014    1   20141
2014    2   20142
2014    3   20143
2014    4   20144
2015    1   20151
```

Then you could change that part of the query to

```
AND rr.sysem = (SELECT max(sysem) 
                FROM register)
```

Which would be very good if sysem was also indexed.